# How query data from a sharepoint list and fill into a repeating table in infopath?

Tags: list, infopath, web-services

I have a form and would like to fill the existing repeating table with data from a SharePoint List. How can I make this? I couldn't find anything about it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create `Data Connection` and Receive data from list you want and set the fields default value as the received data from the `Data connection`

Comment: Hi @Mohamed-arif ! Making this way will have to lock the rows number in the form, right?